# Is there an option i can make it to close the toggle bar when i am clicking anywhere?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to close the menu bar automatically when i click anywhere else on the page but it is not working so kindly help me out with this.

```js
$('.menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
        if (navigation.hasClass('opened')) {
            navigation.removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
        } else {
            navigation.removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
        }
    });
    $('.menu-toggle-close').on('click', function () {
        if (navigation.hasClass('opened')) {
            navigation.removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
        } else {
            navigation.removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
        }
    });
```

Comment: `navigation.toggleClass('opened'); navigation.toggleClass('closed');` remove all `if { ... } else if { ... }`.

Comment: @rockqz - Please add the `html` code too.

Comment: Html code is this: <a href="#" class="menu-toggle btn"><i class="fa fa-line"></i></a>

Answer (score 0):

Add a fixed invisible div between the menu and the page in the background. Then add a listener on this element to close the menu on click:

```
<div id="overlay" style="position:fixed; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0"></div>
```

And

```
$('.menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
    if (navigation.hasClass('opened')) {
        navigation.removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
        this.attr("display", "none");
    } else {
        navigation.removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
        $('#overlay').attr("display", "fixed");
    }
});
$('.menu-toggle-close').on('click', function () {
    if (navigation.hasClass('opened')) {
        navigation.removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
        this.attr("display", "none");
    } else {
        navigation.removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
        $('#overlay').attr("display", "fixed");
    }
});
// Add a listener on the overlay
$('#overlay').on('click', function () {
    navigation.removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
    this.attr("display", "none");
});
```

Opening and closing processes can be factorized into functions.

Answer (score 0):

Add `click` listener to the document, check if it's clicked within the `menu-toggle` section using `closest`, if not remove the `opened` class.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.closest('.dropdown')) {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove('show');
  }
})
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```